# Vite running locally not available via Docker network (host.docker.internal)

Tags: linux, docker, networking, vite

Running a background service in Docker with a docker-compose entry including:

```
extra_hosts:
        - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
```

Running a frontend application **LOCALLY** with a vite.config.ts containing

```
  server: {
    host: "0.0.0.0",
    port: 3000,
  },
```

Vite doesn't seem to be exposed via the docker0 network ... **on my laptop**.
On my desktop, the same settings, after I start my Docker container (along with it's network), Vite will attach to the network on startup and be exposed through localhost, my ethernet IP and a couple of extra 172.* addresses.

I have tried rebuilding docker images, and installing latest Vite.

I expect my Docker service to be able to access the Vite frontend running on my local machine via `http://host.docker.internal:3000`. If I shell into the docker container I am able to ping `host.docker.internal` but port 3000 isn't available. I think this is due to Vite not binding to the docker network on start.

Again, the same setup works fine on my Desktop but not on my laptop. Both running Ubuntu.

**Additional**

The exact setup is:

- Frontend running using vite on localhost
- API running in docker instance, vite is able to talk to the API not a problem
- Worker box is a separate docker container running puppeteer which is being used to generate PDFs by accessing the vite instance on localhost.

This is purely for development, in production the becomes a lot easier.
Again, this setup works fine on my other computer, but not on my laptop.

Comment: You shouldn't need `host.docker.internal` for this.  From a browser, you should be able to use one of the host's non-Docker IP addresses, or `localhost` if it's on the same system; between containers, put them on the same Docker network and use Docker's internal DNS system.

Comment: This is for a puppeteer instance running in docker to access my vite server running on localhost. I shall update the question.